# Oracle - get current date formatted

Tags: sql, oracle, date, truncate, sysdate

I've been wondering - I have a lot of use with sysdate on my system, and when comparing it to my date columns I have to use trunc(sysdate) since the format of sysdate is `DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS` .

I looked over the internet for other functions to return current date on format of `DD/MM/YYYY` but had no luck, `current_date , current_timestamp` and ETC also gives me the hours format..

I need this for better performance when comparing an indexed date column to the current date.

So , anybody know of a system function that returns the desired format? or a way to bypass it?

Comment: If you always use `trunc()` then why don't you just index the "trunc'ed" value?

Comment: I always use trunc on sysdate, not on the column .. the column value's are already trunctated . @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Then what's the performance problem?

Comment: Its not always the case, I have a lot of tables in my db and I am not allowed to alter the table's structure/indexes .. for every table I wanna change its a long bureaucracy process and half of the cases the DBA won't allow it. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Then show us the statements that are slow including the execution plan. I highly doubt that `trunc(sysdate)` is the reason for the statement being slow.

Comment: Its not, each process is different and have different indexes/filters ETC.. so each process should be dealt differently.. But someone told me that trunc(sysdate) interrupt the index to be implemented successfully.. is that a false sentence? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: `trunc(sysdate)` will most definitely **not** "interrupt an index" (whatever that is supposed to mean). But without seing the specific SQL statements that you are having problems with this is impossible to answer.

Comment: No, the format of sysdate is NOT what you said.  SYSDATE, just like all DATE types has an internal binary format.  The format you show is a character string representation of that date (and time) by either an explicit or implicit application of NLS_DATE_FORMAT or the direct use of the TO_CHAR function.  And it is the nature of DATE datatype that it includes a time component.  So if you want to compare two dates with no consideration of the time of day, you MUST trunc the date. And as an aside, if your "date" columns are not of DATE type, you have a serious design flaw.

Answer (score 2):

If your "date" column is of type DATE, then you do not need to be concerned with "format".  You need to compare trunc(column_name)to trunc(sysdate).  And if that is causing serious performance issues because the use of a function eliminates the use of the index, then create a function-based index.  A less elegant solution would be

WHERE mydatecol > trunc(sysdate)
AND   mydatecol < trunc(sysdate +1)

What you do NOT want to do is confuse the binary concept of DATE with the character string representation of a date.  A character string is just a string of characters that you as a human recognize as a data, but to the computer, '2016-02-14' has no more meaning than 'hereisyoursign'.

Answer (score -2):

you may change the variable NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
```

see also http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_nls_date_format.htm

Comment: Won't do the trick, I'm not using oracle directly so it won't help me to alter the session(using through informatica)

Comment: That only changes the _display_ format (or the format assumed for the evil implicit data type conversions). It does **not** remove the time part from the actual date value.